# Why was the drupal-commerce tag nerfed?

Tags: support, tags

I don't understand the decision to remove the drupal-commerce tag in favor of a general e-commerce tag (especially since there's still a tag for Ubercart specific questions). There are questions in here specific to users / developers of the Commerce modules, and I've been referring them to Drupal Answers to use this tag under the premise that I'd be able to easily find and answer questions with the drupal-commerce tag. These aren't "general e-commerce on Drupal" questions, but questions specifically geared toward the Commerce modules - such as one I just answered on currency formatting in Commerce.

How can I get the tag reinstated and past questions re-tagged? Additionally, I had provided a sensible tag description that was never approved... seems whoever first created the drupal-commerce tag had used the description from the cron tag or something.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't see this thread but was reviewing the synonym tag section and actually deleted the [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce) -> [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) tag synonym.

It's true that since this is site about drupal, we should try to avoid having drupal in tag names, however, drupal commerce makes for a good exeption.

- Drupal commerce is a module name (actually a set of modules), which IMO is one of the major modules in Drupal that should be allowed to have it own tag, like ubercart, views cck etc.
- Drupal commerce and commerce are really not synonyms. An example question could be how to create a custom line item type with Drupal commerce. This question is not really about commerce in general, but a specific integration with drupal commerce.
- A lot of other places, like Drupal con, the drupal commerce tag is used as well.
- A lot of people answering questions would like to answer Drupal commerce questions because they are experts, but can't or don't want to answer questions about commerce with Drupal in general. @Ryan is a good example of such a person, since he is the lead developer for Drupal commerce.

So in this example, I think using [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce) is the best option. Also I believe that people using this tag will know that it references the module and not a general concept of commerce with Drupal.

Comment: Should we use "drupal-views" for Views, then? Why in a case should we use the short name of the project, and in the other case we should use a random string?

Comment: @kia I don't get your example. Views is not called drupal-views by any one. Drupal commerce is called Drupal commerce by every one, that is one of my points. Should we then tag questions about drupalgardens with "gardens" and expect people to know what that tag is about? There is no reason the obfuscate tag names to avoid having drupal in them. For most tags drupal should be removed, but there are a few exceptions. That is why we have people and not computers doing a lot of this, as some assessment is needed from time to time,

Comment: The short name of the project is "commerce," in the same way the short name of Views is "views." Your example about Drupal gardens doesn't suit here, because there aren't questions tagged "drupal-gardens."

Answer (score 3):

We're currently refining some of the things about tagging, and it is a bit better if the tags don't reflexively repeat `drupal` where possible.

Comment: What about the case of differentiating Drupal 7 from Drupal 6?

Comment: There is no need to have a tag like [tag:drupal-7] when [tag:7] can be used. Puntually, there are users who add a tag containing _drupal_ because their question is about Drupal, without checking what that tag means and noticing that, for example, they added [tag:drupal-commerce] which is for a specific Drupal module they are not even using.