# Don't allow any tag containing "drupal"

Tags: discussion, tags

As far as I can see, there is just two tags containing "drupal." [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce), and [drupal.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal.org).

For the same reason [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) has been blocked, which is to avoid users who don't know the tags to use start typing "dru" and the system autocompletes it with [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) (which then takes questions to be tagged with [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) when non necessary), also tags like [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce), [drupal.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal.org), and [drupal-gardens](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-gardens) should be blocked.
The first tag doesn't follow the schema used for module tags, for which it has been used the short project name of the module (for [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) is "views", and for [Content Construction Kit](http://drupal.org/project/cck) is "cck"); the second tag is not necessary, as it is not being used for more questions than the ones that already use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably afford to be reactionary here. If you see [drupal-waffles] being used on all sorts of questions that don't involve waffles, then fine - ask for a blacklist. But otherwise, trust that your users will have at least enough sense to recognize that their question, while most certainly about drupal, is only *tangentially* waffle-related.

Though obviously, don't go out of your way to prefix tags with `drupal-` if that isn't actually the proper name of the [library|concept|food] being asked about.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you have the whole [*Version tags considered harmful*](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/version-tags-considered-harmful) discussion mixed up pretty well.

Jeff proposed

> - Eliminating the version tags on existing questions. We can do this in one click globally.
> - Treating version tags as the *exception* not the *rule* on new questions -- if you have a strong case to make that the question you are asking is ONLY relevant to one version and can NEVER EVER be relevant to any other version, then -- and *only then* -- add the version tag.
> - If you encounter an old question that is truly specific to a version, and cannot be edited to be version-agnostic, retag it with a version tag.

What he was basically saying was, it's a bad idea to have the most used tags contain "drupal" because people will use them and only them, instead of thinking what the question was about. He didn't want to ban the tag but limit it's use.

Now this ended up with the tag being renamed to numbers only, to avoid having them showing up in auto complete, which was pretty clever. However the point wasn't to disallow the phrase "drupal" in a tag.

The problem with drupal-version tags was that they were easy to put on any question, would be the most used tags. That combo would have the side effect that users wouldn't think about what their question was about but simply put [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) and be done, instead of enriching the question with more and better meta data. [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce) or [drupal-something](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-something) is not likely to have that effect.

- They wont be the most used tag on the site
- They have a specific meaning that doesn't apply to almost any question.
- They describe the content very accurately.

Like I explained in the [*Why was the drupal-commerce tag nerfed*](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/why-was-the-drupal-commerce-tag-nerfed) question, *commerce* and *drupal commerce* are two complete separate things, which both have meaning in this site.

- [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) is something you should use if you ask a question about anything related to commerce
- [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce) is something you should use for questions about the module.

In some cases you could tag questions with both, but in most cases you cant. The majority of drupal commerce questions is about the commerce API, a few listed below:

- [Formatting currency in Drupal Commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/formatting-currency-in-drupal-commerce)
- [How do I display my products?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/how-do-i-display-my-products)
- [Tax rate on shipping price](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/tax-rate-on-shipping-price)

If you view these questions, it's pretty clear that these questions are not really about commerce, but how to do something with the module. To merge [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) and [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce) tags would obfuscate it's meaning. If I want to see questions about commerce, I get all these API questions that I don't want to see and vice versa.

We used to have a tag called [drupal-behaviors](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-behaviors). This is a good example where drupal is redundant and should be removed. When talking about behaviors in a drupal context, people should know that it is related to the JS API.

So in sort, there is really no reason to go hay-wire over tags containing the name drupal, when that is the most sensible thing to call it. There are a few tags that fit this, and this is okay, since the alternative will bring a mess to the tag system.

Comment: See [this answer by Robert Cartaino](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-is-the-next-step/264#264). @Jeff Atwood also reports that: "Version tags are redundant. The site is already called 'drupal.' We don't need to know that it's _drupal-6_, _drupal-7_, _drupal-8_, _drupal-9_ in every single tag on every single question. It's redundant." Both are saying that part of the problem with that tags is that they start with "drupal." Out of two existing tags, you can find a justification for a tag; what is about all the tags coming from Stack Overflow that contain "drupal-"?

Comment: @kia If I were to comment, I would only repeat myself. Try reading my post again, you are clearly missing something.

Comment: You said "It seems to me that you have the whole _Version tags considered harmful_ discussion mixed up pretty well," which is not true. The "redundant part" to which @Jeff Atwood is referring is having "drupal" in a tag for a Q&A site dedicated to Drupal; @Robert Cartaino then explains why having a tag starting with "drupal" was a bad idea. So, if "drupal-6" was a bad name for a tag (which is now simply "6"), why should "drupal-commerce" be any better? Why didn't @Jeff Atwood decide to keep "drupal-6" instead of blocking "drupal-6" and allowing "6" as tag?

Comment: @kia To keep it short: drupal-6 is a version tag. @Robert wrote _... whenever they started typing D-R-U-P… It pops up in the text completion so users say "oh, I must need a version tag!"..._ Because Drupal-6/7 is a version tag they will automatically be applied to any question. If the user starts typing D-R-U-P and they see drupal-commerce, drupal.org etc they wont think, **WOOT a drupal-something tag I want to use that NOW!!!!** version tags are special and needs to be treated differently.

Comment: Actually, Jeff said explicitly (http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-should-be-reported-as-policy-about-version-numbers-tagging/275#275) to use commerce instead of drupal-commerce. However in this case, as Mark Trapp mentioned, the project is actually called "Drupal Commerce", so the tag imho makes sense in this case. If it turns out to be a problem (questions are tagged incorrectly, we could use "commerce-module" or something like that.